# What are practical methods to acquire a large number of tasks for Meta-learning?

Tags: meta-learning, model-agnostic-meta-learning

It appears that it may be necessary to acquire a very large number of tasks for meta-learning , because **MAML** for example says that each task is analogous to a single training example in regular learning.

This is slightly confusing to me because it appears that outside of automated techniques like **N-way classification** where you randomly sub-select classes (& training examples) to include in a given task.

Adding tasks seems to be quite laborious right? I mean it sounds like you would need to get a different micro dataset for each task? And if meta-learning needs so many tasks then how do you satisfy that need?

Comment: Yes, it does seem that way. You are trying to train something to learn tasks. To learn dogs you need logs of dogs. To learn tasks you need lots of tasks and if the task is detecting dogs then you need lots of dogs for just that one task.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm right. But it seems maybe you don't need a lot of dogs. Because usually meta-learning is few-shot. You maybe just need a few images of lot of animal species.

Unless you are doing an automated method for generating tasks.